# Select (onchange) event with javascript and laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have a select box for groups and another select box for it's items. Below is the javascript function to display the items of a selected group in the select box.

**JS**

```
<script>
 $('#category').on('change',function(e)
 {
    console.log(e);
    var cat_id = e.target.value;

    //ajax
    $.get('/dashboard/ajax-subcat?cat_id=' + cat_id, function (data)
    {
        $('#item').empty();
        $('#price').empty();

        $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj)
        {
            var prices = subcatObj.price;

            $('#item').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+' '+ subcatObj.price +'</option>');
            $('#price').val(prices);

        });
        console.log(data);
    });


 });
 </script>
```

As you can see **$('#food').append(''+subcatObj.name+' '+ subcatObj.price +'');** i have appended the prices in the select as well but i want to seperate the price into another input box. So the input box will also have to dynamic. Depending on the item selected, the input box should contain its price.

But now, with my code, the input box displays just the price of the first item in the select box. It doesn't change when i select a different item

Now, my issue how i can display the prices of the selected item also in another input box?

Comment: could you add your html structure ?

Comment: @Demonyowh, it is just the normal html structure with id and name attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like below

```
<script>
 $('#category').on('change',function(e)
 {
    console.log(e);
    var cat_id = e.target.value;

    //ajax
    $.get('/dashboard/ajax-subcat?cat_id=' + cat_id, function (data)
    {
        $('#item').empty();
        $('#price').empty();

        $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj)
        {
            var prices = subcatObj.price;

            $('#item').append('<option data-price='+prices+' value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+' '+ prices +'</option>');
        });
        console.log(data);
    });
    $('#item').change(function() {
         selectedPrice = $(this).find("option:selected").data("price")
         $('#price').val(selectedPrice);
    })

 });
 </script>
```

Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp
Ref: https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

How I ran on my local system (i hope it simulates your scenario)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="item"></select>
<input type="number" id="price"/>
<script>

    //ajax
    $.get('input.json', function (data)
    {
        $('#item').empty();
        $('#price').empty();

        $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj)
        {
            var prices = subcatObj.price;

            $('#item').append('<option data-price='+prices+' value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+' '+ prices +'</option>');
        });
        console.log(data);
    });
    $('#item').change(function() {
         selectedPrice = $(this).find("option:selected").data("price")
         $('#price').val(selectedPrice);
    })
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

input.json

```
[
{
"price": 12,
"id": "a",
"name": "item1"
},
{
"price": 13,
"id": "b",
"name": "item2"
}
]
```

Then ran these on my local makeshift node server.

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue. It is actually behaving almost like what i have already. It is not dynamic

Comment: Could you please share a complete example somewhere?

Comment: somewhere? WIth your answer, the input doesn't change when the item changes. It still remains at the price of the default selected item

Comment: How about now? I have run this on my local system. It works on my end. Please do test and let me know.